# Strange behaviour of Spring DI

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am injecting dependency in one class. But not finding when I call method of that class.

```
public StudentValidator extends MyValidator implements Validator{

    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
//setter for the same

 public void validate(Object obj,Errors errors){

    validateStudent(Obj) 
 }
}



public class MyValidator{

  private StudentRepository studentRep;

  public void setStudentRep(StudentRepository studentRep){

     System.out.println("This is printing on Tomcat console");
     this.studentRep=studentRep
     System.out.println("This is also printing"+studentRep+" with hashcode");
  }

  public void validateStudent(Object obj){

     studentRep.findStud();  getting here NullPointerException
  }

 }
```

No need of writing Spring servlet as I can see dependency has been injected in setters through Syso statements.

What would be problem for the same?

**UPDATE**

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
   <beans>
        <bean id="studentValidator" class="SyudentValidator" >
             <property name="studentRepository" ref="studentRepository">
        </bean>

        <bean id="myValidator" class="MyValidator">
             <property name="studentRep" ref="studentRepository">
        </bean>

         <bean id="studentRepository" class="StudentRepository">


   </beans>
```

NullPointerException is not my problem. Problem is why I am getting the null pointer in this case as Syso statement is printing my dependencies hashcode.

Comment: You've omitted the setter for the `studentRepository` field for the `StudentValidator` class - does it have the same `println` statement that the setter on `MyValidator` does?

Comment: Yes...In Student Validator I am getting the reference but not in super class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both MyValidator and StudentValidator are spring beans, you should try:

bean id="myValidator" class="MyValidator.java">

bean id="studentValidator" class="StudentValidator.java" parent="myValidator>

You must notify spring that there is an inheritance.

Comment: I have solution for NullPointer. But not for why I am getting that even after my dependency variable is injected with reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a field of type `StudentRepository` twice, which is confusing but here's what I think is going on.

I assume you are creating an instance of `StudentValidator`, which will set the field `StudentValidator.studentRepository`.  However your `validateStudent` method uses the field `MyValidator.studentRep` that will remain `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Basically, only methods can be overridden in Java, not fields.

If you really need this unnecessary inheritance structure, the code should read:

```
public class MyValidator
{
  private StudentRepository studentRepository;

  public void setStudentRepository(StudentRepository studentRepository)
  {
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
  }

  public void validateStudent(Object obj)
  {
    studentRepository.findStud();
  }
}

public StudentValidator extends MyValidator implements Validator
{
  @Override
  public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors)
  {
    validateStudent(Obj) 
  }
}
```

Though I'd be tempted to simplify it to:

```
public class StudentValidator implements Validator
{
  private StudentRepository studentRepository;

  public void setStudentRepository(StudentRepository studentRepository)
  {
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object obj)
  {
    studentRepository.findStud();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the Spring configuration above, I can see you are creating instances of both classes  - not sure why you'd do that if you're not going to use the `myValidator` bean as a parent of the `studentValidator` bean, but either way, if you've only got one bean, using a parent just complicates the Spring configuration of no reason.

The reason you're getting a `NullPointerException` in the `validateStudent` is because you never set the `studentRep` on the `studentValidator` bean, you only set it on the `myValidator` bean (they're two different instances).

Given this, you're Spring config should read:

```
<beans>

  <bean id="studentValidator" class="SyudentValidator" >
    <property name="studentRepository" ref="studentRepository">
    <property name="studentRep" ref="studentRepository">
  </bean>

  <bean id="studentRepository" class="StudentRepository">
```

Though as I said, your class design is confusing in the first place, which makes this Spring config look weird as you're setting a reference to the same bean, `studentRepository`, twice.

My advice would be to apply the class changes I originally suggested, which simply the design as a whole and make it harder to misconfigure you application as is currently happening.

Comment: I got the solution.But my question is it is injected and proof is setter then why again dependency in parent becomes null

Comment: The field in the parent class was never set, you'd overridden the setter in the base class.

Comment: It is set. Hence I am getting hashcode printed please see the setter method of mine.

Comment: You said, you had the same `println` statements in both setters.  If setter on `StudentValidator` overrides the setter on `MyValidator` and doesn't call the `super` then `MyValidator.studentRep` cannot be being set.  If it was being set you wouldn't get a `NullPointerException`, so the setter you listed cannot be being called for the instance that you call the `validate` method on.

Comment: Both the setters are called. Thats why I posted as Strange behaviour

Comment: It's impossible behaviour if both setters are called - Spring isn't magic, fields don't just get unset.  Please post the full code for both classes and the Spring config.

Comment: That's what I am thinking. Is it because as child validator extends it so again new Object is created of Parent class.